# Incomplete WAR automatically uploaded by Maven

Tags: maven, war

To ease up the deployment process of my Jave EE application, I instructed Maven to automatically copy the resulting WAR file to the application server.

pom.xml:

```
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <executions>
                <execution><!-- Run our version calculation script -->
                    <id>Copy to Application Server</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>exec</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <executable>${basedir}/copy-to-appserver.sh</executable>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

copy-to-appserver.sh:

```
scp /home/user/.m2/repository/com/wolf/apix/1.0/apix-1.0.war user@srv-web:/opt/wildfly-8.2.0.Final/standalone/deployments/apix.war
```

Unfortunately, this fails! The WAR is successfully transmitted to the application server, but it's mixed with old and new code. My assumption is that Maven tries to send it while still being in the WAR creation process, because when I run the copy script `copy-to-appserver.sh` manually after the deployment, everything works fine with it on the application server.

My question is, what do I have to change, so that Maven only accesses the WAR file when its creation / manipulation is complete?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your plugin is being executed prematurely in the generate-sources phase

Run it in the last phase by changing the phase to deploy

```
<phase>deploy</phase>
```

Comment: Hey @6ton and thanks for your quick reply. I changed the phase to deploy, but if I now hit `Clean and Build Project` within NetBeans, the script `copy-to-appserver.sh` is not run anymore. How would I deploy the WAR file now?

Comment: The usual build process runs as clean install, deploy come after install.

Answer (score 1):

In addition running the plugin in the correct phase, as suggested by 6ton, you might also want to consider using the [Maven WildFly plugin](https://docs.jboss.org/wildfly/plugins/maven/latest/deploy-mojo.html), which specifically designed to solve your problem. That way, you can get rid of that nasty, nasty script.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to separate the build process and the deployment process cause the `deploy` life cycle phase is intended to upload the artifacts to a remote repository.